# .htaccess how to rewrite api/v2 to be receive on api-v2 file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to receive all calls of

`/data/v2`  on `data-v2` file. Is it possible?

for example my file is `data-v2.php` but i want to have access it with `/data/v2`

Answer (score 1):

Yes , its possible with [Apache mod-rewite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) .

You can use the following rule in your `root/.htaccess` to rewite `/data/v2` to `/data-v2.php` :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^data/v2$ /data-v2.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you but issue is `data.php` is already available. and my old rule is: to remove php extensions for example /data reflects to /data.php but /data/ give 500 error